# postgresql transitive unique constraints via foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,

    t1_id TEXT REFERENCES t1(id)
);

CREATE TABLE t3 (
    id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,

    t2_id TEXT REFERENCES t2(id)
);

CREATE TABLE t4 (
    t4_counter BIGINT NOT NULL,

    t3_id TEXT REFERENCES t3(id),

    // Need UNIQUE constraint on t4_counter + t2_id
);
```

There are 3 postgresql tables (t2, t3, t4) in our system. There are other tables but they are ignored for brevity. Now t2 has an UNIQUE id which is referred in t3 as a FOREIGN KEY. Similarly t3 has an UNIQUE id that is referenced as a FOREIGN KEY in t4. Now in t4 there is a field called `t4_counter`. Now I want to apply a UNIQUE constraint on this table t4, such that, `t4_counter combined with t2_id will always be UNIQUE`.

One easy way to achieve this will be insert `t2_id` as a new column with a `REFERENCES` constraint in the table t4 and then add a `UNIQUE constraint on (t2_id, t4_counter)`. But since we already have the t3_id in the table t4 we should be able to calculate it transitively.

Is it possible to achieve such a unique constraint without adding t2_id in the table t4 ?

I am using postgresql 12+ versions if it matters.

Comment: why you use text as primary key?

Comment: Because of some business logic related constraints. But that should not affect anything here iiuc, right ?

Comment: I think adding t2_id to t4 is the easiest way. You can't have an index (unique constraint) on multiple tables. This thread from 2011 but  still relevant (see responses): https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20110620160307.683ab611%40dick.coachhouse

Comment: Thanks @Jindra I guess that is probably the solution. I too can't figure out anything from google and so asked.

Comment: If a column is not present on a table you can't produce a foreign key. You'll need to add the column `t2_id` as "redundancy", as @jindra mentions, in order to enforce this relationship. You could also use a composite key for table `t4`. That would solve the problem at the database level for good.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the column t2_id as "redundancy", as @jindra mentions, in order to enforce this relationship. You could also use a composite key for table t4. That would solve the problem at the database level for good.

For example:

```
create table t3 (
  id int not null,
  t2_id int not null references t2(id),
  primary key (id, t2_id) -- composite primary key
);

create table t4 (
  t4_counter bigint not null,

  t3_id int not null,
  t2_id int not null,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (t3_id, t2_id) references t3 (id, t2_id),

  constraint uq1 unique (t2_counter, t2_id)
);
```